# Creating a multi page for with sections in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, forms, multipage

Trying to create a 100 question multi page form on Wordpress with style and functionality similar to this ---> https://ibb.co/BnTQL6h

Basically, I am looking to create a form with a total of about 100 questions, broken down into 8 sections. Each section will have about 12 questions. However, each question will be on it's own page. So it's a multi-page form.

I want the users to be able to see their progress, using the progress bar at the top and on the right with the percentage as shown in the image. I'd like them to also be able to see which section of questions they are on with the tabs at the top.

What would be the best approach or tool/plugin to use?

I tried calculated fields form, which is a fantastic plugin, however battling with getting the section tabs and splitting the questions into sections while each question is on its own page

Comment: You may want to take a look at Ninja Forms + their [Multi Step Forms addon](https://ninjaforms.com/extensions/multi-step-forms/). It sounds like that combo would contain the functionality you are looking to achieve